# Why do I need a TV licence to watch non BBC services?

Tags: licensing

Today I learned that the TV licence in the UK is required to:

> watch or record programmes as they’re being shown on TV, on any
> channel

[Source](https://www.tvlicensing.co.uk/check-if-you-need-one?&&WT.mc_id=mec_Search_Brand&gclid=Cj0KCQjwlvT8BRDeARIsAACRFiUnMBxfrZeVMCp-gRvLec4xnADngSvgAfBE5fjNimNR_DBgvvgfdqUaAlGaEALw_wcB)

This means that if I watch, for example, Sky Sports, even on my phone, I require a TV Licence, even though I’ve already paid Sky, and Sky are the ones providing the service.

Given that the TV licence funds the BBC, and that Sky is a paid for service that has nothing to do with the BBC, I’m struggling to see why this is required.

If there were no such thing as a TV licence, and the government tried to bring this rule in now, what possible legal justification could they make for it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its about *why* the law says this, rather than *what* the law says. Questions about why the law says what it does belong on Politics.SE. The short answer to your question is "because Parliament passed a law that says so". They don't need a legal justification, they *are* the legal justification.

Comment: Fair point. I’ll ask this on Politics.SE if you think that’s a better fit. Apologies.

Comment: If you ask on Politics SE, I think the right question would be "why has the UK decided to call the TV tax a licence" -- the UK is not the only country where a public broadcasting system is funded by a tax-like mechanism, yet formally distinct from the tax office, to underline the independence from direct government control.

Answer (score 1):

### Because Parliament passed a law saying you have to

In the UK, Parliament is supreme - if they pass a law requiring everyone to dress in green on the second Tuesday of each month then that is a legitimate and enforceable law.

Why such a law is a bad idea is a political question, not a legal one.